# have Apache return status code 500 for user agent?

Tags: apache-2.2, http

Is the a way I can have Apache return a 500 status when it receives a request from a particular (malicious) user agent?

Comment: Sure, just arrange for your application to crash when it receives such a request. You should consider returning a more reasonable error such as 403 instead.

Comment: The point is to disuade malicious vulnerability scanning. The idea is to respond unreasonably, be it forbidden or server error (server error is preferable as it provides the impression the server isn't able to respond effectively).

Comment: You dissuade vulnerability scanning by putting criminals in prison. You protect your web site by reading [this](https://www.owasp.org/).

Comment: Sorry, but if you put a 500 error in front of a vulnerability scanner, whoever is running it is going to think your app is so badly written that it'll be easy to get in. You will _attract_ unwanted attention.

Comment: @daaa, you've got a reasonable answer now. You might do better editing the question to, "Can I have Apache return an arbitrary error code..."?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it with the [mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). The following entry will return a 403 Forbidden response to clients with the text "Opera" or "MSIE" in their user agent strings regardless of text case.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

If you'd rather return 500 Internal Server Error change the `F` to `R=500` at the end of the RewriteRule directive.